# "SQL logic error or missing database" -error on insert of multiple rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

Query :

```
INSERT INTO "Track"
SELECT "Leonard Collections" AS "Album",
       "Instrumental" AS "Artist",
       "00:02:59.3800000" AS "Duration",
       "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" AS "ReleasedDate",
       "If You Love Me" AS "Title",
       "False" AS "IsPlayableOnLocal"
UNION
SELECT "Leonard Collections",
       "Instrumental",
       "00:02:56.6930000",
       "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM",
       "Espoir",
       "False",
UNION
SELECT "Leonard Collections",
       "Instrumental",
       "00:03:51.6770000",
       "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM",
       "Don't Cry For My Argentina",
       "False"
```

Error :

> SQL logic error or missing database
>
> near "UNION": syntax error

Table :

```
CREATE TABLE Track 
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL , 
    Album VARCHAR(100) NULL , 
    Artist VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT "Artist Unknown", 
    Duration VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    LocalPath VARCHAR(255) NULL , 
    ReleasedDate DATE NOT NULL , 
    Title VARCHAR(255) NULL , 
    IsPlayableOnLocal INTEGER NOT NULL , 
    Rating VARCHAR(255) NULL
)
```

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since you mention latest version of SQLite, you should use multi-valued insert (supported by SQLite since version 3.7.11), like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES
    (1, 2, "abc"),
    (2, 4, "xyz"),
    (3, 5, "aaa"),
    (4, 7, "bbb");
```

This is shorter, faster and less prone to errors. This syntax is also supported by some other databases (at least MySQL and PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 3):

In your second union statement you have superflous ',' character after "False". That is most likely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully tested this into DB Browser for SQLite `Execute SQL` tab > `SQL1` text editor field:

```
CREATE TABLE "FOODS" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "fruits"    TEXT,
    "tastes"    INTEGER UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
 
INSERT INTO "FOODS" (id, fruits) VALUES
    (1, "apple", 1),
    (2, "banana", 3),
    (3, "mango", 5),
    (4, "pear", 2),
    (5, "cherry", 4),
    (6, "pomegranate", 6);
```

https://pastebin.com/naXNRQEk

We must Create the table at the same time as the insertion (as with both statements above together).

Failed tests with trying to execute the `INSERT` statement alone on previously created from the `Database Structure` > `Create Table` button.

(That (alone) does not work in DB Browser for SQLite:)

```
INSERT INTO "FOODS" (id, fruits) VALUES
    (1, "apple", 1),
    (2, "banana", 3),
    (3, "mango", 5),
    (4, "pear", 2),
    (5, "cherry", 4),
    (6, "pomegranate", 6);
```