# SQLite Syntax Error code(1)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am facing problem from long time.

I am dynamically generating insert query in android SQLite database it throws following error.

```
     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: 
            INSERT INTO 'contacts' (id, name, phone_number, email, fax, job, company, website, address, 
            mobile) VALUES(98,'Vijay Bachani','022 - 61608080','','','TRAVEL CONSULTANT','RIYA TRAVEL &    
        TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','237 Gulab Building, P.D Mello Road, Mumbai, 400001',''),
    (99,'Taha Udaipurwala','022 - 61608080','taha.udaipurwala@riya.travel','','JR. CONSULTANT','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS 
    (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','237 Gulab Building, P.D Mello Road, Mumbai, 400001',''),(100,'Salman Lakdawala','022 - 61608080','salman.lakdawala@riya.travel','','JUNIOR CONSULTANT','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','237 Gulab Building, P.D Mello Road, Mumbai, 400001','9768683322'),(101,'Vipul Kharat','022 - 61608080','vipul.kharat@riya.travel','','JR. CONSULTANT','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','237 Gulab Building, P.D Mello Road, Mumbai, 400001','9768215903'),(102,'Abdul Rafiq Siddique','022 - 61608080','rafiq.siddique@riya.travel','','JR. CONSULTANT','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','237 Gulab Building, P.D Mello Road, Mumbai, 400001','9820327417'),(103,'Suryaji More','022 - 61608080','','','OFFICE ASSISTANT','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','237 Gulab Building, P.D Mello Road, Mumbai, 400001',''),(104,'Wayne Joseph','022 - 61608080','','','SR. CONSULTANT','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','237 Gulab Building, P.D Mello Road, Mumbai, 400001',''),(105,'GEORGE THOMAS','022 - 67772300','george.thomas@riya.travel','','GENERAL MANAGER','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','M/1, Leela Business Park, Andheri Kurla road, Andheri (East), Mumbai - 400059','9820128819'),(106,'K P RAMKUMAR','022 - 67772300','ramkumar.menon@riya.travel','','MANAGER','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','M/1, Leela Business Park, Andheri Kurla road, Andheri (East), Mumbai - 400059','9619481065'),(107,'SANDESH CHAVAN','022 - 29258611','sandesh.chavan@riya.travel','','ASST. MANAGER','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','Atlanta Arcade, Ground Floor, Marol Church Road, Opp. The Leela, Andheri (E), Mumbai - 400 059','9619246722'),(108,'SUBRAMANIAN M S','022 - 61608080','subramanian.s@riya.travel','','ASST. MANAGER','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','237 Gulab Building, P.D Mello Road, Mumbai, 400001',''),(109,'JOVITA R. GONSALVES','022 - 29258611','jovita.gonsalves@riya.travel','','TEAM LEADER','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) 
PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','Atlanta Arcade, Ground Floor, Marol Church Road, Opp. The Leela, Andheri (E), Mumbai - 400 059','9881847272'),(110,'SALIM JAMADAR','022 - 
67772300','salim.jamadar@riya.travel','','SR. CONSULTANT','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','M/1, Leela Business Park, Andheri Kurla road, Andheri (East), Mumbai - 400059','9820593817'),(111,'ROHAN SURVE','022 - 67772300','rohan.surve@riya.travel','','ASST. MANAGER','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','M/1, Leela Business Park, Andheri Kurla road, Andheri (East), Mumbai - 400059','8898211973'),(112,'NITHIN K','022 - 61608080','nithin.k@riya.travel','','ASST. MANAGER','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','237 Gulab Building, P.D Mello Road, Mumbai, 400001',''),(113,'MANOJ TAMBE','022 - 61608080','manoj.tambe@riya.travel','','SR. OFFICER','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','237 Gulab Building, P.D Mello Road, Mumbai, 400001',''),(114,'SUBASH N.L','022 - 29258611','subash.nl@riya.travel','','MANAGER','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','Atlanta Arcade, Ground Floor, Marol Church Road, Opp. The Leela, Andheri (E), Mumbai - 400 059','9819517027'),(115,'DAVID M','022 - 29258611','david.m@riya.travel','','OFFICER','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','Atlanta Arcade, Grou
```

Java Code:

```
for (int i=0; i<flag; i++) {

                    JSONObject item = contactsdetails.getJSONObject(k);
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(item.getString("ID"));
                    String name = item.getString("Name");
                    String phone = item.getString("Telephone");
                    String email = item.getString("Email");
                    String fax = item.getString("Fax");
                    String company = item.getString("Company");
                    String address = item.getString("Address");
                    String  job= item.getString("Job");
                    String web = item.getString("Web");
                    String mobile = item.getString("Mobile"); 

                    //sqlString += "INSERT INTO '"+TABLE_CONTACTS+"' ("+KEY_ID+", "+KEY_NAME+", "+KEY_PH_NO+", "+KEY_EMAIL+", "+KEY_FAX+", "+KEY_JOB+", "+KEY_COMPANY+", "+KEY_WEBSITE+", "+KEY_ADDRESS+", "+KEY_MOBILE+") VALUES ("+id+",'"+name+"','"+phone+"','"+email+"','"+fax+"','"+job+"','"+company+"','"+web+"','"+address+"','"+mobile+"');";
                     sqlString += "("+id+",'"+name+"','"+phone+"','"+email+"','"+fax+"','"+job+"','"+company+"','"+web+"','"+address+"','"+mobile+"'),";
                     k++;
                }
```

Really appreciate if help

Comment: You probably forgot to add a space somewhere when creating query. Can you post the code where are you doing this query?

Comment: can u attach the sqlite file created inside data folder in android?

Comment: I cant it has some sensative data

Comment: or you itself first test on SQLiteManger Mozilla's Add-ons....

Comment: Your SQL command is ending with "[...] ,'Atlanta Arcade, Grou". Sure, this is complete? And for being of any help, this is far too long. Make a _short_ example that shows your problem.

Comment: log printed only this

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the string concatenation. Use `?` as positional placeholders. This not only will handle the apostrophes and quotation marks that you are ignoring, but it will help defend you against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert several rows with one `INSERT`. That cannot be done. You need one `INSERT` for each row.

```
INSERT INTO 'contacts' (id, name, phone_number, email, fax, job, company, website, address,  mobile) VALUES (98,'Vijay Bachani','022 - 61608080','','','TRAVEL CONSULTANT','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','237 Gulab Building, P.D Mello Road, Mumbai, 400001','')
INSERT INTO 'contacts' (id, name, phone_number, email, fax, job, company, website, address,  mobile) VALUES (99,'Taha Udaipurwala','022 - 61608080','taha.udaipurwala@riya.travel','','JR. CONSULTANT','RIYA TRAVEL & TOURS (I) PVT. LTD.','WWW.RIYA.TRAVEL','237 Gulab Building, P.D Mello Road, Mumbai, 400001','')
```

and so on... Each of these `INSERT` needs to be executed one by one as well.

Comment: i got error in second loop iteration. in first iteration I have inserted 500 rows in one call

Comment: Sorry I think you're wrong. SQL INSERT syntax doesn't allow that.

Comment: @m0skit0: Actually, that does appear to be valid syntax: http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055566/insert-multiple-rows-in-sqlite

Comment: @CommonsWare Right, but only since SQLite 3.7.11. Android has 3.5.X (or even lower) IIRC.

Comment: @m0skit0: Nice catch (wish the SQLite documentation made that more obvious). However, Android has been shipping with 3.7.11 for a while now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android If your `minSdkVersion` is high enough, it should be safe to use this. That being said, I'd never do it, as it will make the use of positional parameters that much more difficult.

Comment: Then OP should clarify the Android version he's using. In any case, for more compatibility he should not use this syntax.

Comment: @AmolTate Note: *supported by SQLite since version 3.7.11*. What Android version are you using?

Comment: @AmolTate Then syntax is OK, but just keep in mind it will not work for Android < 4.0.

Comment: @m0skit0 I found solution. Thank you for your consideration