# sqlite3 - insertOrUpdate multiple rows by key array

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I got three tables (`person`, `language`, `personSpeaksLanguage`) and I want to `insertOrUpdate` the link table (`personSpeaksLanguage`) by a given id (`personId`) and array of keys (`languageIds`). **How to archive this?**

Example:

```
person
| id | name    |
|  1 | 'Maria' |
|  2 | 'Jim'   |
|  4 | 'John'  |

language
| id | name      |
|  1 | 'english' |
|  2 | 'spanish' |
|  4 | 'japanse' |

personSpeaksLanguage
| personId | languageId | deleted |
|    1     |     2      |    0    |
|    4     |     2      |    1    |
|    4     |     3      |    0    |
|    2     |     1      |    1    |


Example vars: 
  database='./database.db'  
  table='personSpeaksLanguage' 
  personId=2 
  languageIds=[1,2,4]
```

The aim is to achieve that for `personSpeaksLanguage` the values (`2,2`) and (`2,4`) get added. Since (`2,1`) is already in the table. But got softdeleted previously, it should `update` to `deleted = 0`. This is my pitifully try without `update`.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

export default function insertOrUpdateMultiple(database, table, personId, languageIds) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const db = new sqlite3.Database(database);
    let i = 0;
    while (i < languageIds.length) {
      db.run(`INSERT INTO ${table} (id, name) VALUES (${personId}, ${languageIds[i]})`, values, (err) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
      }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          i += 1;
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055566/insert-multiple-rows-in-sqlite) I got:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2, col3) VALUES
    (1, 2, "abc"),
    (2, 4, "xyz"),
    (3, 5, "aaa"),
    (4, 7, "bbb");
```

I combined the languageIds to pairs (`(${personId}, ${languageIds[i]}`) and joined them.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

export default function insertOrUpdateMultiple(database, personId, languageIds, values) {
  const vals = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < languageIds.length; i += 1) {
    vals.push(`(${personId}, ${languageIds[i]})`);
  }
  const valStr = vals.join(', ');

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const db = new sqlite3.Database(database);
    db.run(`INSERT INTO ${table} (personId, languageId) VALUES ${valStr}`, (err) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
    }, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
}
```